# Issue with ng-if and grid-tile

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to hide a grid-tile when the screen size is small or less, at the same time I want show a hidden grid-tile. Both of these grid-tiles contain a d3 graph.
My issue is with loading the graph when the screen size changes; the tile appears but the graph does not load. However, if I refresh the page the graph will load. The issue is illustrated on this codepen (Resize to small window. Refresh).
http://codepen.io/sweatherly/pen/Wxdpwx

```
     <md-grid-tile ng-if="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" md-rowspan="2" md-colspan="9" md-colspan-md="6" md-colspan-sm="4" md-colspan-xs="1">
      <md-card class="graph-card dark-cards" layout-fill>
        <graph></graph>
      </md-card>

  </md-grid-tile>
```

To get the initial load to work I had to use $document.ready({});. I'm not sure how I could apply this to the page resizing/ng-if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `graph` directive has no `link` function. Because, `$document.ready` returns `undefined`:

```
link: $document.ready(function loadGraph() {
    //Code here
});
```

You need to change that to:

```
link: function() {
    $document.ready(function() {
        //Your Code here    
    });
}
```

Please check out this demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akEwok

Comment: If I use ng-show the grid-tile still occupies the space it would as if it were visible. If I don't want an empty space to be there I believe I have to use ng-if (unless there is another way I don't know about). In your codepen the first grid-tile still has ng-if instead of ng-show.

Comment: In both cases, the grid-tile still occupies the space! check out your codepen !

Comment: The grid-tile still occupies space when the graph fails to load when using ng-if. When using ng-show, the tile takes up space even in its 'hidden' state. http://codepen.io/sweatherly/pen/QEavOB

Comment: Please check out the updated answer ! problem fixed !!

Comment: Thank you! I spent a long time trying to figure that out on my own!